# Haven’t, hasn’t, hadn't

Tags: grammar, tense, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Do I say

> His classmates hasn’t been interviewed?”

Or haven’t or hadn’t? It is pretty confusing to me, especially the past perfect, present participle

Comment: has is third person singular and simple present. So **has** does not work. s at the end in English is easy: it always means the verb is third person singular. Allow me to give you some advice....go and find a website that will introduce you to basic verb usage in English. That might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> His classmates **hasn’t** been interviewed?”

This is incorrect because the subject is plural (his classmates). You will have to use either "have" or "had" depending on the tense you want to tell.

So the correct sentence can either be

> His classmates **haven't** been interviewed?”

or

> His classmates **hadn't** been interviewed?”

You can find the meanings and the differences in many sources for example http://www.cws.illinois.edu/workshop/writers/perfectforms/ and https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/
and if you need more then Google.

Comment: If this answers your question correctly then you should mark it as accepted. It's how it works here in SO.